# Geometric meaning of the minimal positive integer $m$ s.t. ideals $I^m\subset J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a unital ring. Suppose $I\subset A$ is an ideal.  Clearly $I\subset\sqrt{I}\subset A$. Suppose $A$ is noetherian or $I$ is f.g. Furthermore assume $\sqrt{I}\subset\sqrt{J}$ for some ideal $J\subset A$. Since $I$ is f.g., there is a minimal $m$ s.t. $I^m\subset J$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there geometric meaning associated to this minimal $m$? And what is the geometric meaning of nilpotent elements in $A/I$? Is this $m$ supposed to be chart independent as well in complex geometric setting?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868958/geometric-differences-between-operatornamespec-mathbbcx-x2-x-and-o/1868973#1868973 See the answer here.

Comment: @Lorenzo That is $m=1$ case for PID. That answer tracks multiplicity information. I am asking whether $m$ minimal s.t. $I^m\subset J$ carries the geometric content. I do not see that post indicating the geometric meaning of $m$.

Comment: This was in regards to your 'geometric meaning of the nilpotent elements in $A/I$'